# Session conflict issue in the application

Tags: .net, session

I have a page where below code is written.

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
 Session["abc"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
else
{
 Response.Write("<li>"+Session["abc"]);
}
```

I am setting the current date time in the abc session variable when user access the page for the first time and trying to show the last visited time to user when user again come to the page. Two user visits the page at two different time take 9:00 AM and 10:00 AM and when they again access the page, these timings sometime displayed correctly but sometime gets swapped. What could be the issue?

Comment: this is can't be, the session is unique for every user because simply it is bonded with the session ID which is unique for every user, did you change any default setting anywhere

Comment: also how do you test this??

Comment: This was recreated during the load testing of the application by two users simultaneously.

Comment: Same question is here in front of us.This comes usually when users visit the page simultaneously.

Comment: what are you talking about please post the ref.

Comment: Code is simple and in front of you.

Comment: oh man I am not asking where I am asking how?? for example do you request the page from 2 Different browsers or form the same browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47087/discussion-between-sanjeev-singh-and-muhammad-nour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly an issue with your IIS settings or IIS itself. Session ID is directly linked to client IP and response can only swapped when IIS is unable relate session id with clients IP.